# Is it possible to train a concrete function?

Tags: tensorflow-lite, tensorflow2.0

I want to convert a model to tflite format. However, I keep getting an error that the operator BroadcastTo is not supported. The only way I have been able to get around this error is by defining by model as a concrete function. How do I train just a concrete function, is it even possible?

(Not my actual model, just an minimal example of the error)

```
    # -------------------- Doesn't Work --------------------

    class CustomLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
      def __init__(self, num_outputs):
        super(CustomLayer, self).__init__()

      def call(self, input):
        trans = tf.ones([1, 25, 37, 12])
        trans = tf.math.add(trans, input)
        m1s = tf.ones([1, 25, 37, 12, 5, 5])
        reshape = tf.reshape(trans, [1, 25, 37, 12, 1, 1])
        f = tf.multiply(reshape, m1s)
        return f

    input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1), dtype=tf.float32)
    f = CustomLayer(1)(input)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=f)
    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
    tflite_model = converter.convert()
    open("model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

```
    # -------------------- Concrete Function (Works) --------------------

    root = tf.Module()
    root.var = None

    @tf.function
    def example(number):
      trans = tf.ones([1, 25, 37, 12])
      trans = tf.add(trans, number)
      m1s = tf.ones([1, 25, 37, 12, 5, 5])
      reshape = tf.reshape(trans, [1, 25, 37, 12, 1, 1])
      f = tf.multiply(reshape, m1s)
      return f

    root.func = example
    concrete_func = root.func.get_concrete_function(3)
    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions([concrete_func])
    tflite_model = converter.convert()
    open("model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Note that I have already tried the following solutions:

1. Defining the model in **Keras** (so it can be trained easily) and using

   ```
   tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model
   ```
2. Saving the Keras model as a **SavedModel** and using

   ```
   tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model
   ```
3. Saving the Keras model as a SavedModel and getting the concrete function from it using

   ```
   concrete_func = model.signatures[
   tf.saved_model.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY]
   ```

I know it is also possible to make a custom operator, but that would require advanced knowledge of tensorflow's C++ API, knowing how BroadcastTo works internally, knowing where to put the files, compiling a custom AAR, and building a custom JNI layer.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code!!**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow_hub as hub

model_path='/content/model.h5'
model=keras.models.load_model(model_path)
reloaded = keras.models.load_model(model_path,custom_objects{'KerasLayer':hub.KerasLayer})

TFLITE_MODEL = f"path/model.tflite"


# Get the concrete function from the Keras model.
run_model = tf.function(lambda x : reloaded(x))

# Save the concrete function.
concrete_func = run_model.get_concrete_function(
    tf.TensorSpec(model.inputs[0].shape, model.inputs[0].dtype)
)

# Convert the model to standard TensorFlow Lite model
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions([concrete_func])
converted_tflite_model = converter.convert()
open(TFLITE_MODEL, "wb").write(converted_tflite_model)
```